# Automatically Resize Overflowing Text With CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

I currently have the following code:

```html
<p style="font-size: 20em; max-width: 100vw;">Hellooo!</p>
```

As you can see, the font-size is too large for the screen. I want the text to stay at its set size until it overflows the screen (My attempt is the `max-width`, but that is not working). Is there a way to fix this with CSS and HTML only?

Since I want the text size to be `20em` unless it overflows the screen, I do not want to set the `width` to any value other than `20em`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`min` should do it.](https://caniuse.com/minmaxwh)

With a known font, you can also use a good fallback.

```css
p {
  font-size: min(20em, 28vw);
  
  /* Next rules are only be have a clearer preview */
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Hellooo!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of text, you can use the CSS min() function with your em sizing and the maximum size dependent on the viewport. Otherwise you are going to need a polyfill.

```html
<p style="font-size: min(20em, 12vw); max-width: 100vw;">Hellooo!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS calc function and change the font size based on the vw value.

```
<p style="font-size:calc(25vw)">Hellooo!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `media-queries` and variable units(`vw`) will solve!

```css
.mytext{

}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {/*adjust*/
  .mytext {
    font-size: 20em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {/*adjust*/
  .mytext {
    font-size: 20vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="" class="mytext">Hellooo!</p>
```